# Seemingly simple python regex does not match

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup's (python) find_all function with a regex to scrape some data off a webpage. Quite specifically, I'm scraping individual classified ads from [here](http://www.avito.ru/rossiya). If you inspect each classified ad, you can see they are typically encapsulated in either of the following divs:

```
<div class="item c-b-#">...</div>
```

or

```
<div class="item c-b-# premium">...</div>
```

where `#` is a number (typically 0 or 2).

My goal here is to tell these two apart using a regex. Here's what I've done:

```
regularAds = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': re.compile('item.*')})
```

and

```
premiumAds = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': re.compile('item.*premium')})
```

The former works as expeced - it returns *all* classifieds (including premium), but the latter returns nothing. What is wrong with it? Why doesn't `'item.*premium'` map to the second div-class?

As a secondary question: How would I alter the first regex to say "I want all those that have the word `'item'` but not the word `'premium'`?

**EDIT**

For future reference: after a little trial and error the answer to my secondary question became:

```
regularAds = [tag for tag in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': re.compile('item')}) if 'premium' not in tag['class']]
```

which worked nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My quick guess is that `class` from beautiful soup is basically the result of calling `class.split(' ')` on the actual text of the class attribute.  What if you do:

```
premiumAds = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'premium'})
```

Comment: Wow... It worked! I never would've guessed. Sort of weird behavior I think. Not exactly intuitive either, but it explains a lot (I've struggled with some similar issues before). Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped!  I think it does it this way to similar to `classList`.

Answer (score 0):

Weird idd as your second regex should definitely work:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<div class="item c-b-#">text1</div><div class="item c-b-# premium">text2</div>')
>>> soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': re.compile('item.*premium')})
[<div class="item c-b-# premium">text2</div>]
```

What about `soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': re.compile('^item((?!premium).)*$')})` for your last question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the regex itself is correct, but cf. @sam 's suggestion above, the class attributes are split on ' ', so that pretty much narrows it down. Your regex worked fine though; returned the same as `.*item.*`.